# WebSharper VSIX does not install on Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate?

Tags: websharper

I have Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate installed on my machine and I tried to install WebSharper project templates using provided VSIX. However I see nothing, the VSIX just starts and exits, nothing happens.

I tried installing other VSIX, both directly and from Extension manager and they all worked without any problem.

Could you please advise what might be a problem in my case? I have Visual F# 3.1 installed via VSIX and working.

Comment: Filed a bug, thx! https://bitbucket.org/IntelliFactory/websharper/issue/266/vsix-problems-on-vs-2013-ultimate

Comment: @toyvo Thank you, do not hesitate to ask me for any configuration info you need to know to reproduce it!